# Why Kendo DataSource using custom method for endpoint communication sends always the same object for deletion?

Tags: javascript, kendo-datasource

I have a Kendo Grid where I use custom methods for communicating to the server. These methods implemented using Restangular.

I can add (create new) objects as many as I want without any problem.

Scenario 1:

- Open the page
- click on the "Delete" button in the line - it uses the inbuilt "destroy" command
- record will be deleted
- select another row and click on the "Delete" button
- error, because Kendo sends the first attempt's dataset not the second one
- if I reload the page it works fine

Scenario 2:

- delete a record (if it is the first one after refreshing the page it works fine)
- add a new record
- result: the record will be added and there will be an additional delete call to the server containing the same data I sent in the previous step

Properties of datasource:

- [Autosync](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-autoSync) is set to false
- [batch](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch) is set to true

What I did so far:

- I have read a few questions and answers here and the Telerik's Forum, but there is nothing usable answer.

I assume the problem can be that, the server returns something different than it is expected by Kendo Datasource. My service endpoint returns a HttpStatusCode.Accepted (202) and there is no data attached. But I cannot find any informatioon at Telerik about their expectations. Not to mention that it is not defined what should be returned after deletion.

Have somebody met this issue and solved it?
Does anybody know what does Telerik's Datasource expects to be returned from the server after deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud#update-remote) that the empty response treated as success in case of update. Moreover, I have passed through the result of delete to e.success() and it caused the strange behavior.

```typescript
private destroyModuleScreen( e: kendo.data.DataSourceTransportOptions ): kendo.data.DataSourceTransportOptions {

            var contract: IKendoModuleScreenContract = <IKendoModuleScreenContract>( e.data.models[0] );

            this.moduleScreensService.deleteModuleScreen( contract ).then(( result: any ) => {
                e.success();

                //wrong
                //e.success(result.plain());
            }, ( reason ): any => {
                e.error( reason );
            });

            return e;
        }
```